# How is energy conserved in formation of chemical bonds?

Tags: energy-conservation, physical-chemistry, molecules, binding-energy, quantum-chemistry

I understand that when an H$_2$O molecule is formed, it has lesser total energy than the constituent (2H and O) atoms. I also understand that the potential energy (PE) will be reduced when the atoms come closer, and the kinetic energy (KE) will increase, but the decrease in PE is more than increase in KE. So where does the remaining energy go? Is it the KE that gets transferred to surrounding molecules that appear as heat or is it given off as radiation or a combination of both.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, the formation of chemical bonds comes with a spontaneous release of energy. This is is in the form of electromagnetic radiation of wavelength matching the energy gap between the lowest-energy bound states and the unbound states. This energy is often quickly thermalized by absorption and distribution of vibrational energy among surrounding molecules, which manifests as the system heating up. In this case, it is rather difficult to actually observe the electromagnetic radiation that is released since it is quickly dispersed in the surrounding medium. But whether we think about the transitions in terms of heat or radiation, radiation is the more accurate description of the quantum mechanical process that is occurring. In the case of gases, it is perfectly possible to actually observe the release of various wavelengths of light directly, though getting the individually separated gas-phase atoms in the first place is certainly non-trivial.

The reason that electromagnetic radiation is released can be rationalized with an anharmonic model of molecular vibration such as the [Morse oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_potential). An example of the Morse potential energy curve for the ground electronic state of iodine is shown below. You can clearly see the various vibrational states, each hiding a series of rotational states as well (not shown for clarity). At the dissociation limit, the molecule really does not properly exist, as the states more resemble the continuum that characterize the individual atoms. It is only when the atoms become sufficiently close and release radiation that a molecule forms and the energy is dissipated by radiative transitions to the lower vibrational and rotational levels. The relative probability of releasing this radiation is controlled by the transition probability, which can be explained by [Fermi's golden rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_golden_rule) of time dependent perturbation theory. In a nutshell, the electric dipole moment transition integral controls the relative probability of these transitions.

It is also important to point out that your claim that the kinetic energy will increase for the specific particles is not entirely well-founded. In the sense the the atoms in the bound molecule are vibrating with a characteristic vibrational energy, this concept makes sense. But in the sense that the atoms are no longer translating independently with the same velocity (and the overall molecular speed is likely much lower), it does not. A more careful analysis should be done here. The only obvious fact is that the potential energy surface characterizing the electronic energy as a function of internuclear distance is dramatically lowered by the bonding of these atoms.

[image]

Comment: Modeling of chemical reactions do not require direct emission and subsequent thermalization of radiation, and crossed molecular beam experiments could measure the emission of radiation but generally do not, hence it is not correct to say chemical reactions occur with release of electromagnetic radiation.

Answer (score -1):

You are basically correct.  The kinetic energy of the newly formed water molecules is by definition heat.  The radiation observed is emitted after the reaction as the product ($H_{2}O$) cools.

Here's some references with more information:

- [Rocket fuel is the chemical reaction to form water from hydrogen and oxygen](https://blogs.nasa.gov/Rocketology/tag/liquid-oxygen/#:%7E:text=Liquid%20oxygen%20(LOX)%20serves%20as,creates%20one%20homogenous%20solid%20propellant.&text=Hydrogen%2C%20the%20fuel%20for%20the,normally%20exists%20as%20a%20gas.)
- [A similar reaction can be modelled with just kinetic energy of the products, no direct emission of radiation](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article-abstract/95/10/7298/443694/Quantum-reactive-scattering-of-four-atom-reactions)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/432483)

Comment: This is a good point but the answer is complete as-is, this is not a link-only answer.